# Standardizing Controller + Service method signatures

Tags: c#, .net, mvc, asp.net-web-api

In my controllers, I have the following:

```
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    [Route("api/report")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Report(ReportDto report)
    {
        await _profileService.SubmitReportAsync(User.Identity.Name, report);
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, true);
    }
```

Then in my service method (and in all service methods), I have the following:

```
public async Task<ApiResponseDto> SubmitReportAsync(string username, string ReportDto report)
{
    try // repeated
    {
       using (var db = new DbContext()) // repeated
       {
         // this is where the unique stuff is
       }   
    }
    catch(Exception e){ // repeated
       HandleServiceLayerException();
    } 
 }
```

My issue is that I'm repeating so much "signature" code in my service methods.  How can I simplify, keeping in mind that service methods have varying parameter signatures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a helper method for executing a query where you wrap the entire `try/catch` error handling and pass the query via a lambda expression:

```
private async Task<T> ExecuteAsyc<T>(Func<DbContext, T> query) 
{
    try
    {
        using (var db = new DbContext())
        {
            return query(db);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        HandleServiceLayerException();
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

Then you call it like this with a lambda:

```
public async Task<ApiResponseDto> SubmitReportAsync(string username, string ReportDto report)
{
    return ExecuteAsyc(context => 
    {
        // this is where the unique stuff is
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Finally getting around to implementing this - do you know whet I should return in the catch block, and how I can go about awaiting `query`?

Comment: @SB2055 you're right, I forgot to put the `default(T)` inside the `catch`, I fixed it.

Comment: Cool, thanks.  And should we be awaiting `query` at all?

Comment: @SB2055 it's enough to await the SubmitReportAsync or any other public API as they already return a Task that can be awaited.